# Multiple Image upload on array - Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I wanted to upload some array of images through JavaScript. I tried the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count =0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
        count++;
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
          var file = e.target;
          $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
            "<br/><span class=\"removeImg\">Remove image</span>" +
            "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
          $(".removeImg").click(function(){
            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
          });

          // Old code here
          /*$("<img></img>", {
            class: "imageThumb",
            src: e.target.result,
            title: file.name + " | Click to remove"
          }).insertAfter("#files").click(function(){$(this).remove();});*/

        });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }
});
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### HTML

```
  <div class="field" align="left">
      <h3>Upload your images</h3>
      <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
    </div>
```

But somewhere, when I click the submit button on my form, it sends me only array of one file, which is the last updated file. I wanted array of it..so that I can process that data later.

Please help me out.

Comment: At first `count` in your code indicates the number of selecting file, but in for-loop you iterate files from 0 to `count`, but not to `filesLength`.

Comment: I tried first with the filesLength only....but when I post my form it returns only one array of image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have tested your code it's working fine you just need to replace count variable in for loop with the filesLength variable then you will get all the images not last one that you were getting before!! below is the corrected code. do run the code it will work for you!in upload.php when write  you will get number of images you have selected!

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var count =0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    $("#files").on("change", function(e) {

      var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
        console.log(filesLength);
        count++;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
          var file = e.target;
          $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
            "<br/><span class=\"removeImg\">Remove image</span>" +
            "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
          $(".removeImg").click(function(){
            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
          });

          // Old code here
          /*$("<img></img>", {
            class: "imageThumb",
            src: e.target.result,
            title: file.name + " | Click to remove"
          }).insertAfter("#files").click(function(){$(this).remove();});*/

        });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }
});
</script>


<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
  <div class="field" align="left">
      <h3>Upload your images</h3>
      <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


    <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="field" align="left">
          <h3>Upload your images</h3>
          <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Have you submited the form? Cause I run this code inside a PHP form. At browser side, the stack of images are visible.. But when I submit my form it returns me this

`[files] = array (
                          [0]=>Image1.jpg
)`

Comment: can you provide me your jquery function which is passing images to another page where you are not getting all the images!?

Comment: how are you submitting your form?bz i used action in form tag and i am getting all the images that i am selecting on the action page!

Comment: No! it still didn worked out...I am calling a controller while submitting the form..and i fetch all the data over there...but only one image is fetched...not every..i tried giving id's to all images..that too didn worked...can you help me out? @kiran gadhvi

Comment: Hey it worked...that happened only when I have to keep the shift button pressed and upload multiple files

Comment: you can also use CTRL button either! that was totally unexpected thing!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112161/discussion-between-kiran-gadhvi-and-jijo-nair).